# Is it safe to return a shared object by reference with "std::lock_guard<mutex>"?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, standards

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

mutex g_mtx;
vector<string> g_coll;

void Cleaner()
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(g_mtx);
    g_coll.clear();
}

const vector<string>& Getter()
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(g_mtx);
    return g_coll;
}

int main()
{
    g_coll = { "hello" };
    auto fut = async([&]()
    {
        Cleaner();
    });

    auto returned_coll = Getter();
    fut.get();
}
```

If `Cleaner` is executed after `return g_coll;`, does the C++ standard **guarantee** that `returned_coll` contains `{ "hello" }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not safe.

Semantically, the order of events when a function of non-void return type returns is as follows:

1. The expression in the return statement is evaluated.
2. The return value is copy-initialized from said expression.
3. Automatic local variables are destroyed in the reverse order of construction.
4. Control is returned to the caller.

Note that `returned_coll` is not the return value. Rather, `Getter()` is the return value. The initialization of `returned_coll` from the lvalue returned by `Getter()` occurs after step 4.

Therefore, when `returned_coll` is copy-initialized from `Getter()`, the mutex held by `Getter` will have already been released, which means the initialization of `returned_coll` may race with the access in `Cleaner`.